# Can't ctrl-c my SDL apps anymore

Tags: c, linux, opengl, signals, sdl

Yesterday I could and today I can't `ctrl-c` in the terminal to kill my SDL apps. Before `SDL_Init` is called, everything works as expected. After, `ctrl-c` does nothing. Calling `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL)` doesn't change this. I haven't updated anything I can think of except for Nvidia drivers. This happens with apps I've compiled months ago too.

**Is there any way to debug what's happening?**

*[EDIT]*
Even this ceases to work after `SDL_Init` (although behaves normally within `gdb`):

```
signal(SIGINT, exit);
raise(SIGINT);
```

The same happens with both SDL1.2.15 and SDL2 (glut is ok though). I'm running Fedora 18 (x64), gcc 4.7.2, nvidia drivers 331.2 with a gtx titan.

`SDL_QUIT` occurs when I hit the close button on the window, but never `ctrl-c` (afaik it never used to either - SIGINT would simply kill the app).

*[EDIT2]*
This isn't consistently reproducible but is very common. Sometimes running other programs beforehand such as `echo` gives an increased chance for `ctrl-c` to work. If it doesn't work, repeats never works.

After some further testing it seems `ctrl-c` stops working only when `SDL_INIT_TIMER` is passed to `SDL_Init`. **What could the timer subsystem have to do with signals??**

*[EDIT3]*
Here's my test case...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_GLContext context;

    fprintf(stderr, "Start");
    usleep(3000000);
    fprintf(stderr, ".\n");

    //raise(SIGINT); //always works

    struct sigaction old;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, &old);

    fprintf(stderr, "Init");
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE);
    //SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE); //no problems
    fprintf(stderr, ".\n");
    usleep(3000000);

    sigaction(SIGINT, &old, NULL);
    //signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    //raise(SIGINT); //fails with SDL_INIT_TIMER (commonly, but not always)

    fprintf(stderr, "Window");
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("sdlwin", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    fprintf(stderr, ".\n");
    usleep(3000000);

    fprintf(stderr, "Context");
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    fprintf(stderr, ".\n");
    usleep(3000000);

    fprintf(stderr, "Loop...\n");
    while (1)
    {
        usleep(1000000);
        printf(".\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In some cases the first `ctrl-c` just works. Sometimes the first ends the current `usleep` and it takes a second to kill the app. Other times, `ctrl-c` never works. The randomness makes me assume there's something uninitialized somewhere. Annoyingly I've just had a run where `ctrl-c` worked 90% of the time with only a couple of fails.

Comment: SDL_QUIT is *never* raised, despite assigning a signal handler or not? What is your environment and your SDL 1.2 version? 1.2.15?

Comment: In SDL2's [`src/events/SDL_quit.c`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/cff03048babd/src/events/SDL_quit.c) does control flow ever reach [`SDL_HandleSIG()`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/cff03048babd/src/events/SDL_quit.c#l35) on your machine when you Ctrl-C?

Comment: @genpfault no, it's not reached. `SDL_QuitInit` invokes `sigaction(SIGINT` with `sa_handler = 0x0`, so SDL isn't even trying to change default behaviour. `ctrl-c` works as expected in `gdb` so it's really difficult to debug.

Comment: @genpfault actually, this is wrong sorry. `gdb` broke a few lines too early and reported the wrong line number. Yes, `SDL_HandleSIG` is called successfully, while debugging. Currently the only way to reproduce the issue is while not debugging and with `SDL_Init(... | SDL_INIT_TIMER)`.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/744313/2293156 maybe it would works to you

Comment: @TomásBadan I'm pretty confident the problem lies before the signal handler. `SDL_QUIT` is never generated and the program never exits when this bug occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having similar issues for a few days... and after a long and painful investigation I reached to [this bug report](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/638521/linux/gnome-terminal-problems-ctrl-c-and-exit/) in the NVIDIA OpenGL drivers.

The problem is that the initialization code of the NVIDIA OpenGL librariy corrupts the sigprocmask of the process. This may happen to any process that links to that library. In my case the session manager was affected, so every single process in my session inherited it.

You can check if that is your case with the following command:

```
$ grep SigBlk /proc/<pid>/status
```

The normal output should be:

```
SigBlk: 0000000000010000
```

If you instead get a big number that looks like a memory address, you have the bug.

Downgrading to 325.15-11 will solve your problems.

Comment: Many thanks! `SigBlk: 65031d7a527068ae` with `SDL_INIT_TIMER` and `SigBlk: 0000000000000000` without (not sure why I don't have a `1` like you). Strange I only see this with specifically SDL *and* a specific config.

Comment: @jozxyqk: That 1 is, I think, SIGCHLD, it depends on the process being watched. About the _specific config_, I guess it is an uninitialized/overwritten `sigmask_t` in the NVIDIA code, and it depends on the particular memory layout of the process. I got it only with many libraries loaded, never with simple programs. Also, the bug seem to be triggered when a thread is first created...

Comment: This driver bug to be resolved now. I was still having the problem of not being able to Ctrl+C, and Gavin's answer was the right one https://stackoverflow.com/a/20171501/1565581

Answer (score 3):

After looking through the SDL source, it seems that passing `SDL_INIT_EVENTS` it `SDL_Init` will cause SDL to use its own signal handling function. In `SDL_quit.c` we have:

```
/* Both SIGINT and SIGTERM are translated into quit interrupts */
(and the code that does that)
```

You can simply reverse this with

```
#include <signal.h>
...
struct sigaction action;
sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &action);
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);
....
```

The SDL signal handler does nothing but push an `SDL_QUIT` event onto the event queue (and reset the signal handler), so simply reversing it should be okay if you don't need to handle the quit event.

By default, `ctrl+c` should push `SDL_QUIT` onto the event queue. On my computer it works this way as long as a window is created. Try printing the types of all polled events, and see if `ctrl+c` sends any event at all. Also, if you are using `SDL 1`, consider using `SDL 2`.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I have exactly that preserving `sigaction` code set up. I also poll for the `SDL_QUIT` event. Neither restoring `sigaction` or catching `SDL_QUIT` works for me if `SDL_INIT_TIMER` is passed to `SDL_Init`. Doing so seems to disable certain system signals entirely but I don't know how to debug it since running in `gdb` produces the correct behaviour. The same happens with both SDL 1 and 2 and only started happening recently.

Answer (score 0):

SDL by default handles the usual signals, not sure why it didn't before.

To avoid it and revert to the standard signal handling, pass in the flag `SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE` to `SDL_Init()`.

Comment: I'm testing with a `std::cin >> i;` to pause execution and give me a chance to `ctrl-c`. The init line is currently `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE)`. I can ctrl-c directly before this but still not after. I'm also polling for `SDL_QUIT` which is never triggered either.

Comment: @jozxyqk: Oh, my bad! The parachute is only for fatal exceptions. Ctr-C (aka. SIGINT) is treated differently, and it cannot be easily redirected. What I do is `Ctrl-Z` and then `kill -9 %1`.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a workaround, not an answer...*

Don't pass `SDL_INIT_TIMER` to `SDL_Init`. `SDL_GetTicks` still works just fine without it (or at least it seems to, maybe it's still needed on other platforms). I don't know if other [timer subsystem](http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryTimer) features are affected because I don't use them. It probably wouldn't hurt to use another timing method for higher accuracy too.